# Compare DataTables case-insensitive in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, comparison, datatables

I have this following code. Which I use to compare two DataTables (One is populated from SQL Server and other from Oracle). Comparison is working fine but when I try to perform case-insensitive comparison it gives me an error.

```
bool compareTables(string tb1, string tb2, bool matchCase)
    {
        DataTable table1 = getTable1(tb1);
        DataTable table2 = getTable2(tb2);
        bool equal = true;
        int equalCount = 0;
        int unEqualCount = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
            {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                bool result;
                if (matchCase)
                    result = array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
                else
                    result = array1.SequenceEqual(array2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                if (result)
                {
                    equalCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    unEqualCount++;
                    equal = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return equal;

    }
```

I have this in mind that this "StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase" parameter will not work with ItemArray from the DataTable. Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 'object[]' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid argument